# How do I combine multiple values in an AND OR statement in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, filter, count

I am using the following script in a call to my database:

```
SELECT 
 1.0*(COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name"='Done'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__project__key"='FLUM'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__issuetype__name"='Task'
 OR "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__issuetype__name"='Story'))/
 (COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name" IN('To Do','In Progress','Done')
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__project__key"='FLUM'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__issuetype__name"='Task'
 OR "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__issuetype__name"='Story'))
FROM "stitch_jira"."issues"
```

Basically, It should be getting TASKS and STORIES that are DONE, then dividing them by the total number of tasks and stories. The results don't see to demonstrate this. IT works fine if I only do Tasks, or only do stories, but not when I do both.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You mean that the result is different from the division of the individual results? That would surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was as follows:

```
SELECT 
 1.0*
 ((COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name"='Done'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__project__key"='FLUM'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__issuetype__name"='Task'))
 +
 (COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name"='Done'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__project__key"='FLUM'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__issuetype__name"='Story')))
 /
 ((COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name" IN('To Do','In Progress','Done')
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__project__key"='FLUM'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__issuetype__name"='Task'))
 +
 (COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__status__statusCategory__name" IN('To Do','In Progress','Done')
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__project__key"='FLUM'
 AND "stitch_jira"."issues"."fields__issuetype__name"='Story')))
FROM "stitch_jira"."issues"
```

The issue was that there was not tight enough binding of the OR condition and it was pulling in data in it's calculations outside of the filtered project.